# Removing invisible borders from table with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` block with a `table` inside.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='ribbon'><table id='topMenu'>
<tr>
<td><a href='index.php'>Home</a></td>
<td><a href='links.php'>Links</a></td>
<td><a href='about.php'>About</a></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ribbon {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #C2F4FF;
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 20px; }

a { text-decoration: none; }

#topMenu { height: 20px; }

#topMenu td { padding: 0 10px 0 10px; }

#topMenu td:hover { background-color: red; }
```

Here's a 100% height screenshot of `div` with pointer over "Home":
http://i.imm.io/1f7fd.png

I think, invisible `table` borders are the reason of those gaps between red area and `div` top and bottom sides. I would like to know about how to expand that `td` thing to the real 100% height so that were no gaps, and make red cell occupy the whole `div` height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following styles to your CSS:

```
#topMenu{
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYR4A/)

But please don't use a table for non-tabular data - See [M1K1O's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231044/1612146). Despite what you may/probably will hear, table's do have their uses, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: I don't quite understand that "non-tabular data". Can one-row menu be considered as non-tabular data? It's just a horizontal list, I think.

Comment: See [this link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm) about tabular data

Answer (score 3):

Try use `<ul> <li>` instead of `<table>`:

```
<div id='ribbon'>
    <ul id='topMenu'>
        <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='links.php'>Links</a></li>
        <li><a href='about.php'>About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#ribbon {
    background-color: #C2F4FF;
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#topMenu {
    height: 20px;
    margin:0 padding: 0;
}
#topMenu li {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#topMenu li:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4eqq/

Comment: `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` are the solution to my problem, but using `<ul>` is a nice option, too. Thanks, will use it.

Comment: According to @F4r-20, the best way of navigation structure is `<ul>`. `<table>` use just for tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` properties.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-collapse

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-spacing

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the space with
`border-spacing: 0;`